# Trigger to alert delete and insert

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can we create a trigger to send an email on any insert or delete action on a table.It should send an email and also it should have the location of the server and the database. Please, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup dbmail in SqlServer 2005 (if you haven't already).
Inside the trigger, just send something like:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@recipients=N'me@address.com',
@subject=@sbj,
@blind_copy_recipients=N'you@address.com, himtoo@address.com',
@body=@Msg ;
```

Obviously fill the variables - you can pull them from the inserted data.  Basic trigger info is easy to find in BOL, we pull the insert with:

```
(select * from inserted)
```

then assign to the variables like:

```
SELECT @Msg = MessageText, @Subject= Subject FROM Inserted
```

Where MessageText and Subject would be columns in the inserted row. Just add your own variables for the Location and ServerName if you like...